# print panel using javascript in c# but i want with page number on footer

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

print panel using javascript in c# but i want with page number on footer

**my code js**

```
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function PrintPanel() {
                var panel = document.getElementById("<%=pnl_print.ClientID %>");
                      var printWindow = window.open('', '', 'height=400,width=800');
                      printWindow.document.write('<html><head><title></title>');
                      printWindow.document.write('</head ><body style="Font-              family:calibri;">');
                      printWindow.document.write(pageFooter);
                      printWindow.document.write(panel.innerHTML);
                      printWindow.print();
                      printWindow.document.write('</body></html>');

                      printWindow.document.close();
                      setTimeout(function () {
                          printWindow.print();
                      }, 500);
                      return false;
                  }
        </script>
```

**pannel want to print**

Page

```
    </div>
```

Button click how to print page no in footer

**my button on client click**

please give any suggestion...

css that i was used in my code

```
    @page {
    @bottom-right {
    content: "Page " counter(page) " of " counter(pages)
    }
}
```